# extract elements from array and subtract them

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

What I want to do is that if for example I have a list of items that I wanna sell, every item has a  String name and int price, and I add them to an array(could be an arrayList I'm not sure what would be better, cause I would like it to be userinput) and say I add many elements to that array like this: [item1, 50, item2, 100, item3, 200] What I want to do is extract one of the items, item1 for example with its price: 50 and sell it for an amount equal to the price or bigger, and then put the item1 that I sold for a 100 into another array of my sold items. I wanna be able to do this with every item.
I don't even wanna start coding cause I have no idea how to do it.

Comment: "I don't even wanna start coding". What a phrase

Comment: "I don't even wanna start coding" than pay someone to code for you. this is not charity.

Comment: I only said that cause I know that if I start doing it without really comprehending it it's gonna be useless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So long as each item is Unique I would use a `Map` for this:

Say for example I have:

1. Apple
2. Pear
3. Twix

I would then want to track how many items I have, and which ones were sold:

```
Map<String,List<Item>> itemsSold = new HashMap<>();
```

Then create an `Abstract` class for each item that would look similar to this:

```
public abstract class Item {

    private String ItemId;
    private double ItemCost;
    private double ItemSellPrice;
    private boolean ItemSold;

    public Item(String ItemId, double ItemCost) {
        this.ItemId = ItemId;
        this.ItemCost = ItemCost;
    }

    public String getItemId() {
        return ItemId;
    }

    public void setItemId(String ItemId) {
        this.ItemId = ItemId;
    }

    public double getItemCost() {
        return ItemCost;
    }

    public void setItemCost(double ItemCost) {
        this.ItemCost = ItemCost;
    }

    public double getItemSellPrice() {
        return ItemSellPrice;
    }

    public void setItemSellPrice(double ItemSellPrice) {
        this.ItemSellPrice = ItemSellPrice;
    }

    public boolean isItemSold() {
        return ItemSold;
    }

    public void setItemSold(boolean ItemSold) {
        this.ItemSold = ItemSold;
    }

}
```

Then, you can `extend` Item to create a class for each Item like "Apple" and "Pear" and set the values for the class.

Inside the `Map<String,List<Item>> itemsSold = new HashMap<>();` You could use the `Array.size()` to see how many "Apples" you have, and then add / get / remove them as you see fit per sales, etc.

Java is an Object Orientated programming language. Creating a nice Object for your items can help simplify your code, and increase you OOP skills.

Using a method like this, allows you to extend, and add additional code for each item as you need, and then you can use various methods for tracking the items, including their sales.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can use 2 `ArrayList<Pair<String,Integer>>` one for items and the another one for sold for each input add `new Pair(yourItemNAme,price)`to the ArrayList
then for each sold item check if the price is greater that or equals to the item `price` then remove it from the `items list` and add its `name` with the new `price` to the `sold list`.